# Make dictionary to count words in multiple strings

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Working in a pandas data frame, one column is just strings and I'd like to create a single dictionary (separate from data frame) the with keys made from the words of the strings in each of the rows for that column, and the values of those keys being the count of the number of occurrences of each word/key.

I read something about the Count subclass but I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Would it be possible to use the solution in a lambda function?

Comment: Share what you've tried so far

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
words = pd.Series(['foo bar baz', 'foo bar amazing', 'amazing stuff is cool foo'])
words.str.split().explode().value_counts().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 3, 'bar': 2, 'amazing': 2, 'baz': 1, 'stuff': 1, 'is': 1, 'cool': 1}
```